# How to find all files with same name in different directories and update specific text in each file in Linux_Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, find-and-replace

I've a bunch of files with same name "abc.php" in different directories. I want to find all files and replace the specific line of text i.e, "hello" to "bye" in each file. I've the text multi times repeat in each file that i've to update. Is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 2):

This finds all *.php files in your current directory `.` recursively and replaces "hello" with "bye" multiple times in each line it finds.

```
find . -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/hello/bye/g'
```

Make sure you make a backup of your current directory before you apply this.

Or alternative:

```
find . -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i'.bak' 's/hello/bye/g'
```

This will create a backup before applying the replacements, e.g. "abc.php" -> "abc.php.bak".